# How to find nearby cities from a given city

Tags: here-api

HERE has a lot of endpoints but I am struggling to find one that will take city name or coordinates and return nearby cities within  radius (limited to cities/towns only).

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/resource-coverage-search.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the API Product you are using, so I searched a solution for the [JS HERE API](https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api).

---

**Get Cities**

Ref: [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/resource-coverage-city.html)

*Table 2.* Filter by cities around a point location within a radius (all parameters need to be set).

This parameters are mandatory:

```
{ details: Integer, nearbyMax: Integer, radius: Integer, center: Double }
```

[see more...](https://developer.here.com/search?q=cities%20within%20a%20radius)

Comment: I get only a few cities, but not all cities in this radius

Answer (score 3):

Check out the HERE Reverse Geocoder.
Use parameter `level=city&mode=retrieveAreas`

See the full doc at https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html

Comment: and maximum radius is 150 km. Does somebody know a better API?