# How can I get a list of cities and neighborhoods in UAE through HERE Map (here-api)

Tags: here-api

We are using HERE map, how can we extract the list of `neighborhoods/districts` and `cities` using JSON? Currently we are using manually created lists of `neighborhoods/areas` that then sometimes can't be matched to an area in the actual HERE map or areas are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in this [How to find nearby cities from a given city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709608/how-to-find-nearby-cities-from-a-given-city) post.

Additionally, you can refer to Platform Data Extension API if you need more city level information. Refer https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=MEA&release=18144&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=CITY_POI_0 to see the fields you will get using PDE. Hope you find it useful!